# How to handle/preserve null values when using Hive INLINE/EXPLODE on nested array columns

Tags: sql, arrays, apache-spark, hive

I have a table with many columns, some of which have values that are JSON structs. Example:
`[{"code":"meddra:10021135","onto":"meddra","syns":["deficiency vitamin","vitamin deficiency","hypovitaminosis","meddra:10021135","hypovitaminosis nos","avitaminosis","vitamin depletion","unspecified vitamin deficiency","hypo...],"term":"Hypovitaminosis"}]`. There are about 15 columns like this with different sources of data.

Thanks to this [previously answered post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62085384/4480594), I can now use INLINE to extract the information I need to new columns and SELECT what I need. However, certain rows are often null if that source of data has nothing, and so INLINE seems to skip those rows altogether.

How do I properly specify that if a certain value is NULL in the INLINE tables I'm generating, it will preserve the row and skip to the other variables, and preserve the NULLS in the resulting output?

My SELECT statement to set up the INLINE columns extracted from the JSON is:

```sql
SELECT id, term, code, exploded_array.*, exploded_mesh.*

FROM mytable

LATERAL VIEW INLINE(meddra_data) exploded_array

LATERAL VIEW INLINE(mesh_data) exploded_mesh

LIMIT 50
```

From the above line, this would parse JSON into these new columns

```
| code            | onto   | syns                                              | term            |
|-----------------|--------|---------------------------------------------------|-----------------|
| meddra:10021135 | meddra | ["deficiency vitamin","vitamin deficiency","hy... | Hypovitaminosis |
```

However, if one of the above SELECT targets is NULL, the entire row is omitted from the output. How do I preserve the row data (including NULLS) and let the query move onto the next variables?